# PDF and report image files to table

Tags: spotfire

I am using Spotfire and I have hundreds of print image reports that a client receives daily. I would like to extract the data in these reports into table form and combine them together into a single table so that we can do analysis on the entire time period.

The example of the report is as follows

```
$CL04303 UNCLAIMED MAIL REPORT                          02122015
                                                                                                                PAGE:   1

                                                     UNCLAIMED MAIL REPORT
                                               TRANSACTION DATE = 02/11/2015

POLICY NUMBER: ABC80230 CLIENT NAME:  Andrew                                         auditid: H8G3J1AY

PRIOR ADDRESS:
428 SANDOVAL ST


SANTA FE NM 87501-7312

NEW ADDRESS:
1583 PACHECO ST STE B



POLICY NUMBER: XYZ05720 CLIENT NAME: Mike                                              auditid: H8G3HIZE

PRIOR ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

NEW ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

POLICY NUMBER: KJU10110 CLIENT NAME: TOM                                       auditid: H8G3HIZE

PRIOR ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

NEW ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933


            page 1

                                                INDIVIDUAL POLICY SERVICES                                         PAGE:   2
                                                    DALLAS SERVICE CENTER
                                                     UNCLAIMED MAIL REPORT
                                               TRANSACTION DATE = 02/11/2015

POLICY NUMBER: LIP60004 CLIENT NAME: Eric                                            auditid: H8G3HIZE

PRIOR ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

NEW ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

POLICY NUMBER: PYT04785 CLIENT NAME: Linda                                        auditid: H8G3HIZE

PRIOR ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933

NEW ADDRESS:
6047 WEST END BLVD


NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933
```

I want the resulting data table to look like this:

```
Policy_Number       Audit_Trail Prior_Address_01    Prior_Address_02    Prior_Address_03    Prior_Address_04    Prior_Address_05    New_Address_01  New_Address_02  New_Address_03  New_Address_04  New_Address_05
KYT24045    JAYANT  JUYHIZE 19 GREENGROVE AVE           INDIANAPOLIS IN 46234-2722      72 WEIR LAKE RD         SOMERS NY 10589-1735    
KYT63030    MARYNETTA   JUYJJ6A 19 GREENGROVE AVE           INDIANAPOLIS IN 46234-2722      72 WEIR LAKE RD         SOMERS NY 10589-1736    
KYT63051    MARYNETTA   JUYJJ6A 858 W 83RD ST           BRONX NY 10457-2713     858 W 83RD ST           SOMERS NY 10589-1737    
KYT65454    MARYNETTA   JUYJJ6A 858 W 83RD ST           BRONX NY 10457-2713     858 W 83RD ST           NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1933   
KYT73439    MARYNETTA   JUYJJ6A 858 W 83RD ST           BRONX NY 10457-2713     858 W 83RD ST           NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1934   
KYT87866    KAREN   JUYJ1AY 858 W 83RD ST           BRONX NY 10457-2713     858 W 83RD ST           NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1935   
KYT03747    CRYSTAL     JUYJX4N 35 JOHNSON RD APT 70            YONKERS NY 10705-2422       165 BLOOMFIELD DR APT L5            NEW ORLEANS LA 70124-1936   
KYT01138    ROSALINDA   JUYJ5IX 119 JOSEPHINE ST            YONKERS NY 10705-2422       119 JOSEPHINE ST            NEW ORLEANS LA 70113-1428   
KYT43124    ROSALINDA   JUYJ5IX 4724 VICTORY BLVD APT 202           YONKERS NY 10705-2422       3316 GOLDMEDAL AVE          SANTA FE NM 87501-7312  
KYT46829    LINDA   JUYJ1AY 4724 VICTORY BLVD APT 202           CHICAGO IL 60621-1129       3316 GOLDMEDAL AVE          SANTA FE NM 87501-7313  
KYT44940    LINDA   JUYJ1AY 8 CREEKVIEW LN          CHICAGO IL 60621-1129       620 ARRINGTON RD            SANTA FE NM 87501-7314  
KYT44946    LINDA   JUYJ1AY 8 CREEKVIEW LN          CHICAGO IL 60621-1129       620 ARRINGTON RD            SANTA FE NM 87501-7315
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done in Spotfire or any other method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a job for Spotfire, but for an OCR tool. From the OCR tooling, some form of textmining to get everything in the right shape and maybe then it can be used for reporting in Spotfire.